# App chooses a wrong database path

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, connection

I use a database called db.sqlite for my iPhone App.
For finding the correct path I use the following code:

```
- (NSString *) filePath {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
```

}

This returns the following Path:

```
/Users/*******/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/E1D5F78D-7FD2-45D7-A3DE-B53BCBB9BDC5/Documents/db.sqlite
```

But the database at this path is newly created and empty.
When returning the right path as a string it works well, but I don't think this will work on the iPhone.

```
return @"/Users/*******/workspace/xcode/MyApp/MyApp/db.sqlite";
```

What did I do wrong or forgot doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is for getting a file from the app's Documents sandbox directory. Based on the path you want, you need to get the file from the app's resource bundle.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

Keep in mind that your db.sqlite file is read-only inside the app bundle. Do not make any attempt to write to this database file.

If you need to write to the database, you must first copy the file to a writable location (such as the Documents directory). Then use that copy of the file for all reading and writing.

Comment: Can I (Do I have to) copy the file by code or has it to be done manually? And how do I get the right file onto the iPhone afterwards?

Comment: It has to be done via code. Normally you check if the file exists in the Documents directory. If not, you copy the template from the bundle. Then you use the file from Documents.